# Apex - Convert comma-separated String to a List

Tags: apex

How to convert below String into `List<String>` in `Apex Programming` ?

```
String alpha = 'A, B, C, D';
```

In java, its very easy like below:

```
List<String> result = Arrays.asList(alpha.split("\\s*,\\s*"));
```

Comment: you can use split(' , ').  alpha.split(' , ');

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Salesforce provide [String class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm) which can be used to work with string. In your case you can use [Split method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_split)

```
String alpha = 'A, B, C, D';

List<String> lstAlpha = alpha.split(',');

System.debug(lstAlpha);
```

Comment: Just a note if you are using the pipe "|" as a delimiter the split function does weird things e.g:
String alpha = 'split | this | sentence';
List<String> lstAlpha = alpha.split('|');

Answer (score 4):

@Nebula - because pipe (|) is a regex symbol, using following code splits the string properly

```
String alpha = 'split | this | sentence'; 
List<String> lstAlpha = alpha.split('\\|');
```